# The display prop that I used in mui grid component is not working . I want to hide that grid when it is xs and sm

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, box

```
  <Grid container item className={classes.mainGrid} >
                    <Box component={Grid}
                        item
                        md={6} sm={6} xs={12}
                        className={classes.firstgrid}
                        display={{ xs: "none", md: "block" }}>
                        
                        <Paper elevation={6} className={classes.firstpaperSignin}>Sign in</Paper>
                    </Box>
```

I tried this idea and it is not working . i want to hide the box when it is in xs and sm

Answer (score 0):

You are using `container` and `item` simultaneously in `Grid`. parent should be container and child should be `item`. please check below code.

```
<Grid container className={classes.mainGrid}>
  <Grid item md={6} sm={6} xs={12} display={{ xs: "none", md: "block" }} className={classes.firstgrid}>
    <Paper elevation={6} className={classes.firstpaperSignin}>Sign in</Paper>                       
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```